# How can I test to see whether gevent monkey patching is active?

Tags: gevent

Is there any "official" way my library can test to see whether gevent monkey patching has been activated?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about an official way, but here's a way.

Notice `os.fork` changes when it gets monkey patched:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.fork
<built-in function fork>
>>> import gevent.monkey; gevent.monkey.patch_all()
>>> os.fork
<function fork at 0x100535140>
```

And notice what `gevent.fork` is:

```
>>> import gevent
>>> gevent.fork
<function fork at 0x100535140>
```

So, when monkey patching all (or just os):

```
>>> is_monkeypatched = gevent.fork == os.fork
```

Answer (score 3):

See the [docs](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.monkey.html#querying).

```
from gevent import monkey

monkey.is_module_patched('socket')
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "no" (and, obviously, one would expect to see an API provided in [the docs](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.monkey.html) if there were).

The longer answer is "mostly", using `monkey.saved`. Checking the source you can see that effectively all the usual patching updates this dictionary with references to the original items, so they can be retrieved using `monkey.get_original()`. This isn't official if you believe officialness requires documentation, but it doesn't seem to be meant as an internal API despite it not being exported in `monkey.__all__`.

If by your question you mean simply "has any monkey-patching occurred?" then you could just test `if monkey.saved: ...`.

If you mean "has module XXX been monkey-patched?" then you could test for the appropriate name, e.g. `if "threading" in monkey.saved: ...`

For reference, after doing a `monkey.patch_all()` here's what you'd see in there. (Note that patch_all() doesn't actually patch everything. It leaves out subprocess, sys, and Event by default, so I included them below.)

```
>>> import os, gevent
>>> os.name, gevent.__version__
('posix', '1.0.1')
>>> from gevent import monkey
>>> monkey.patch_all(subprocess=True, sys=True, Event=True)
>>> monkey.saved.keys()
['socket', 'thread', 'ssl', 'gevent.socket', 'subprocess', 'sys', 'threading', 'time', 'os', 'select']
```